deploying Remix backend(Hono) to cloudflare workers with wrangler
My plan is to have a remix project where the client is hosted on Vercel and the server is through Cloudflare Workers. I'm using Hono to handle the server side. I'm having trouble setting up the wrangler.toml and vite.config.ts to deploy without failure. My current setup has these 6 errors.
X [ERROR] Build failed with 6 errors:

  build/server/nodejs-eyJydW50aW1lIjoibm9kZWpzIn0/index.js:3042:15: ERROR: Top-level await is
  currently not supported with the "iife" output format
  node_modules/@hono/node-server/dist/index.mjs:5:35: ERROR: Could not resolve "http2"
  node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:5:1407: ERROR: Could not resolve "fs/promises"
  node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:22:5137: ERROR: Could not resolve "async_hooks"
  node_modules/react-router-hono-server/dist/node.mjs:11:57: ERROR: Top-level await is currently not
  supported with the "iife" output format

Here is my wrangler.toml file.
name = "NAME"

account_id = "NUMBERS"
workers_dev = true
node_compat = true
compatibility_date = "2024-09-14"

[build]
command = "npm run build"
[build.upload]
format = "modules"
main = "./build/server/nodejs-eyJydW50aW1lIjoibm9kZWpzIn0/index.js"
compatibility_flags = ["nodejs_compat"]
[[build.upload.rules]]
type = "ESModule"
globs = ["**/*.js"]
fallbacks = ["lightningcss"]

[env.production]
name = "WORKER NAME"
route = "https://WORKER-NAME.USER-NAME.workers.dev/*"

My vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import { remixDevTools } from "remix-development-tools";
import { routes } from "./remix/config";
import { vercelPreset } from "@vercel/remix/vite";
import { iconsSpritesheet } from "vite-plugin-icons-spritesheet";
import json5 from "vite-plugin-json5";
import { Mode, plugin as markdown } from "vite-plugin-markdown";
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill";
import { devServer } from "react-router-hono-server/dev";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    remixDevTools(),
    iconsSpritesheet({
      inputDir: "./resources/icons",
      outputDir: "./app/library/icon/icons",
      withTypes: true,
      fileName: "icon.svg",
    }),
    json5(),
    markdown({ mode: [Mode.MARKDOWN] }),
    remix({ routes, presets: [vercelPreset()] }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
    devServer({
      entry: "app/entry.server.tsx",
      exclude: [/^\/(resources)\/.+/],
    }),
    NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
      process: true,
      buffer: true,
    }),
    NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
  ],
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        format: "esm", // I changed this to 'esm'
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      buffer: "buffer",
      process: "process/browser",
      stream: "stream-browserify",
      util: "util",
    },
  },
  define: {
    POSTHOG_API_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.POSTHOG_API_KEY),
    POSTHOG_API_ENDPOINT: JSON.stringify(process.env.POSTHOG_API_ENDPOINT),
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["@prisma/client"],
  },
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
});

my deploy script:
"deploy": "wrangler deploy --minify --name WORKER-NAME ./build/server/nodejs-eyJydW50aW1lIjoibm9kZWpzIn0/index.js",

I'm using react-router-hono-server to help with hono.
I don't know what else to share that could help understand the project more.
Here is the entry.server.ts
const ABORT_DELAY = 5000;
// Initialize environment variables
const env = initEnv();

export default async function handleRequest(
  request: Request,
  responseStatusCode: number,
  responseHeaders: Headers,
  remixContext: EntryContext,
  loadContext: AppLoadContext
) {
  //console.log(`Handling request for URL: ${request.url}`);

  let callbackName = isbot(request.headers.get("user-agent"))
    ? "onAllReady"
    : "onShellReady";

  let instance = createInstance();
  let ns = i18nextConfig.getRouteNamespaces(remixContext as any);

  await instance
    .use(initReactI18next) // Tell our instance to use react-i18next
    .use(Backend) // Setup our backend
    .init({
      ...i18n, // spread the configuration
      lng: loadContext.locale, // The locale we detected above
      ns, // The namespaces the routes about to render wants to use
      backend: { loadPath: resolve("./public/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json") },
      resources,
    });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let didError = false;

    let { pipe, abort } = renderToPipeableStream(
      <I18nextProvider i18n={instance}>
        <RemixServer context={remixContext} url={request.url} />
      </I18nextProvider>,
      {
        [callbackName]: () => {
          let body = new PassThrough();

          responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "text/html");

          resolve(
            // @ts-expect-error
            loadContext.body(body, {
              headers: responseHeaders,
              status: didError ? 500 : responseStatusCode,
            })
          );

          pipe(body);
        },
        onShellError(error: unknown) {
          reject(error);
        },
        onError(error: unknown) {
          didError = true;

          console.error(error);
        },
      }
    );

    setTimeout(abort, ABORT_DELAY);
  });
}

export interface LoadContext
  extends Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getLoadContext>> {}

export interface ExtendedContext extends Context {
  loadContext?: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getLoadContext>>;
}

export const getLoadContext = async (c: Context) => {
  const locale = i18next.getLocale(c);
  const t = i18next.getFixedT(c);
  const clientEnv = getClientEnv();

  return {
    db: prisma,
    locale,
    t,
    env,
    clientEnv,
    body: c.body,
  };
};

declare module "@remix-run/node" {
  interface AppLoadContext extends Omit<LoadContext, "body"> {}
}

export const server = await createHonoServer({
  async configure(server) {
    // Call FIRST
    server.use("*", i18next(i18nextConfig));

    // Middleware to set the `db` property in the context
    server.use("*", async (c: ExtendedContext, next) => {
      const loadContext = await getLoadContext(c);
      c.loadContext = loadContext; // Attach loadContext directly to the context
      await next();
    });

    // Add api route handlers
    server.route("/api", printfulRoutes);
    server.route("/api", resendRoutes);
    server.route("/api", cloudinaryRoutes1);
    server.route("/api", sessionRoutes);
    server.route("/api", userModelRoutes);
    server.route("/api", productModelRoutes);
    server.route("/api", orderModelRoutes);
    server.route("/api", noteModelRoutes);
    server.route("/api", dashboardRoutes);
    server.route("/api", categoryModelRoutes);
    server.route("/api", cartModelRoutes);
    server.route("/api", addressModelRoutes);

    // Handle all other requests with Remix
  },
  getLoadContext,
});

